# C++ strange parameter passing

Tags: gcc, c++11

I got a strange behavior while i was giving parameters. The header of my method is:

```
class Acceptability {
  public:
    Graph* G;                               
    std::unordered_set<node>* community;    
    std::unordered_set<node>* shell;        
  public:
    Acceptability(Graph& G, std::unordered_set<node>& community,
                  std::unordered_set<node>& shell);
    virtual ~Acceptability();
    virtual double getValue(node v) = 0;
};
class NodeClusterSimilarity: public Acceptability {
  public:
    NodeClusterSimilarity(Graph& G, std::unordered_set<node>& community,
                          std::unordered_set<node>& shell);
    virtual ~NodeClusterSimilarity(); 
    virtual double getValue(node v);
};
```

The constructors of both classes are the following:

```
GreedyCommunityExpansion::Acceptability::Acceptability(
    Graph& G, std::unordered_set<node>& community,
    std::unordered_set<node>& shell) {
  this->G = &G;
  this->community = &community;
  this->shell = &shell;
}
GreedyCommunityExpansion::NodeClusterSimilarity::NodeClusterSimilarity(
    Graph& G, std::unordered_set<node>& community,
    std::unordered_set<node>& shell)
  : Acceptability(G, community, shell) {
}
```

While testing my implementation, I create an object of type `NodeClusterSimilarity` with `community {0}` and `shell {1,2,3}`. Then i call the method `getValue()` and the surprise was:
size of the `community` after passing the parameters is `1` (hurraaaaaaas!!!) 
but size of the `shell` was `0` :(( [the expected value is obviously `3`]

Can any one tell me, what's going wrong?

Comment: Please post the implementation of your constructors.

Comment: It would be useful to also see the test code that calls those constructors.

Comment: Since your constructors take references and do not copy them, you must call them with variables that persist at least as long as your objects.  Is that the case?

Comment: constructors:  GreedyCommunityExpansion::Acceptability::Acceptability(
 Graph& G, std::unordered_set<node>& community, std::unordered_set<node>& shell) {
 this->G = &G;
 this->community = &community;
 this->shell = &shell;
}

Comment: GreedyCommunityExpansion::NodeClusterSimilarity::NodeClusterSimilarity(
 Graph& G, std::unordered_set<node>& community, std::unordered_set<node>& shell): Acceptability(G, community, shell) {
}

Comment: //this is the relevant test portion
Graph G(5);
 G.addEdge(0,0);
 G.addEdge(0,1);
 G.addEdge(0,2);
 G.addEdge(0,3);
 G.addEdge(1,2);
 G.addEdge(1,4);
 G.addEdge(2,3);
 G.addEdge(2,4);
 G.addEdge(3,4);


 std::unordered_set<node> first, shell;
 first = {0};
 shell = {1,2,3};

GreedyCommunityExpansion::NodeClusterSimilarity ncs1(G, first, shell);

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling you created `community {0}` and `shell {1,2,3}` in-place when testing. i.e.

```
NodeClusterSimilarity similarity( graph, {0}, {1,2,3} );
```

In that case you're taking the addresses of temporary rvalues, that are deallocated by the time you call `getValue()`.  You have two options:

- `community` and `shell` have to outlive your `NodeClusterSimilarity` instance. Basically have them as separate variables on the stack before calling the constructor.
- Make the members be `const &`, if you're not modifying them, and they should bind to the rvalues and keep them alive for the lifetime of `Acceptability`

Concretely for the second point:

```
class Acceptability {
  public:
    Graph const& G;
    std::unordered_set<node> const& community;
    std::unordered_set<node> const& shell;
  public:
    Acceptability(Graph const& G, std::unordered_set<node> const& community,
                  std::unordered_set<node> const& shell);
    virtual ~Acceptability();
    virtual double getValue(node v) = 0;
};
```